# Can't retreive values from bootstrap-selectpicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a `bootstrap` `multiple select-picker` (not `select`) elements where my goal is to get the values out of them.

```
 <select id="custom_include" class="selectpicker" name='custom_include[]' data-header="Select target Groups" multiple data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" data-title="Target Groups"  data-show-tick="true" data-none-results-text="No groups matching" data-style="" data-style-base="form-control">
        {% for group in target_groups %}
           <option value="{{ group }}">{{ group }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

When I try searching by value:

```
$('#custom_include').val()
```

It returns only the first selected item in the dropdown.

When trying to search by selected text:

```
$('#custom_include').find("option:selected").text()
```

returns  selected items stuck to each other as strings like the following example:

```
'dj dj.jewar@xol.comha ha.nyen@xol.com'
```

where the first entry is `dj dj.jewar@xol.com` and the second is `ha ha.nyen@xol.com`

When trying `.text()`

```
$('#custom_include').text()
```

it returns the entire content of the dropdown regardless what was selected.

For me it seems impossible but is there a way to return the selected values as arrays?

However, so far this seemed impossible to get all selected values.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen please check the question again, I explained how this doesnt work

Comment: 1) `It returns only the first selected item in the dropdown` - no it doesn't, it returns an array: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/vkgyhxr1/ 2) Your `select` has the `id` of `target_groups` not `custom_include`.

Comment: *`.text()` returns items stuck together* - yes, that's how `.text()` works - it returns a single string.  Try (OTOMH) `$('#custom_include').find("option:selected").map(e => $(e).text())`

Comment: @freedomn-m I get a `index.js:36 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when doing that

Comment: Not sure about that error, but my bad, as it was OTOMH, should be `.map(i, e) =>` as it's jquery map (I normally double check) and even the two jquery .map functions have their arguments swapped.   https://jsfiddle.net/vwLjoa1n/  As noted above `$("select"0.val())` return an array: https://jsfiddle.net/vwLjoa1n/1/